# .Net SDK 2.1.300-rc1 leaves dangling .Net Core Hosts

Tags: c#, .net-core

We have a PS script that loops through a bunch of directories (each has a different .Net solution in it) and builds all of our microservices.  There are ~30 of them. The script is just calling `dotnet build` in each of the directories it visits and waiting for the build to complete.

What I've noticed is that this now leaves behind a bunch of running .Net Core Host processes in the background after I installed the .Net Core 2.1 SDK release candidate (2.1.300-rc1-008673).  When using the old SDK (2.1.4) this doesn't happen: the .Net Core Host processes are killed immediately after each build completes when using 2.1.4.

[image]

I've tried adding the following flags:
/p:UseSharedCompilation=false
/p:UseRazorBuildServer=false
But these didn't appear to have any impact on the dangling processes.

Any ideas on how to make it stop leaving these behind?

Comment: There is a new command `dotnet buildserver shutdown` that might help: https://github.com/dotnet/cli/pull/8950#discussion_r178253999. Also, please file a bug for this behaviour - that's one way developers get feedback about a bad design.

Comment: @swanee what happens when you add `/m:1` to the build commands? that should keep msbuild from starting up nodes.

Comment: @omajid I did add the shutdown command at the end of the batch script and that seemed to work, although it's not 100% ideal because it leaves all the processes running until everything is done instead of shutting them down after they finish.  But that is a workable solution. Small correction: It's dotnet build-server shutdown.

Comment: @MartinUllrich That seems to have done the trick! That's what I was looking for.  If you want to publish that as the answer, happy to give you credit.

Comment: @swannee `/m:1` is a synonym to `-m:1`. It doesn't matter until you try to find the documentation for the first one. The doc says that it is the default value: "If you don't include this switch, the default value is 1." (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-command-line-reference). But if it solved your problem suddenly then I would suppose that `dotnet build` used some other values when it was calling `msbuild` under the hood. It looks like you had multi-process build and now if you use `/m:1` you will get single-process one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apart from the Roslyn compiler service (`/p:UseSharedCompilation`) and Razor build service (`/p:UseRazorBuildServer`) msbuild also has a concept of multi-process builds and node reuse.

You should be able to tell MSBuild to shut down worker nodes after completion using

```
dotnet build /nr:false
```

or disable multi-process builds altogether (may result in slower builds) using

```
dotnet build /m:1
```

Comment: Both of those swtiches worked, but in my case, /m:1 yielded significantly faster build times, by about 30% over the course of 30 solutions running 5 in parallel at a given time.

Comment: @swannee , if single threaded build helped you so much then there should be something really strange happening. How many cores do you have on that system? I guess that it was `-m` by default. It means it was spawning as many processes as CPU threads you have. If you have say 16 CPU threads then I would try `-m:2`, `-m:4`, ... to see maybe those will be faster for you.